# How to add dotted background on heading tags?

Tags: css

my goal is to add white background to the text and dotted background to the right without adding any more markups.

```
<div class='widget'>
<h2 class="title">
  title here
</h2>
</div>

widget { 
  width: 400px;height:400px;
  margin: 120px auto;border:1px solid #f00;
}
h2.title {
  margin:5px;padding:0 5px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABZJREFUeNpi2r9//38gYGAEESAAEGAAasgJOgzOKCoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
color: #f00;
}
```

[My fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/willrpx/kL6of97m/1/)

I tried using before/after pseudo classes,display inline, floats but still cannot make it to work.

Comment: Never seen it done without extra markup, like a span around the text.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jLqe5y4t/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not the best solution, but you can try something like this:

```
h2.title:first-line{
    background: #fff;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kL6of97m/4/)

Comment: Hi dude, this one seems to be working. I'm new to css and my first time seeing ":first-line". I will check if it will work with other browser. Thanks

Comment: this one is still the best solution so far, the only issue is it's hard to adjust or add a space between the text and the background. But this is a good start.

Comment: try something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL6of97m/7/). I have added an :after with content and margin

Answer (score 1):

Add this styles to your css

```
background-position:right;
background-size: 30px 20px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

you can change the size of background.

so it will be

```
    .widget { 
  width: 400px;height:400px;
  margin:20px auto;border:1px solid #f00;
}
h2.title {
margin:5px;padding:0 5px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABZJREFUeNpi2r9//38gYGAEESAAEGAAasgJOgzOKCoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
color: #f00;
    background-position:right;
    background-size: 30px 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Hi dude, by the looks of it, I doubt if it will work. I tried and as expected, it didn't. Thanks anyway for the reply.

Comment: what is your browser?

Comment: chrome, but I check the outcome on other browsers as well.

Comment: remove h2 text and add this
h2:before{

    background-color:white;
    content:'  title here'
}

Answer (score 0):

You can give an offset to the background using something like
background-position: 100px top;

The problem is that the "background-repeat" property should be set to "don't repeat".